# using tesseract 4 with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

I have used tesseract 3.04 with python and pytesseract(from Pypi) now I want to use the new LSTM based 4.00.00alpha
I'm using kali linux so i installed libtesserct4(using apt-get) it created its folder named 4.00 in tesseract-ocr but when I try to use it with pytesseract it does not recognize --eom input
the code is:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename),lang="en",config='--eom 2')
```

Result:

```
read_params_file: Can't open 1
```

oem input does not also appear when I use tesseract -h command.

It does not recognize training data files in folder tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata it only recognize training data in the folder tesseract-ocr/tessdata
If there is any problem with pytesseract could you please tell me how to setup a python wrapper for tesseract 4

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr). It supports Tesseract 4 and is a true wrapper around the C++ API in contrast to pytesseract which just calls tesseract CLI.
Training is a whole different story and you should follow the guide provided by the developers.

Comment: WOW somebody answered this!!!Thank you I'll check the repository out, I don't want to train it just wanted to use the prepared training files for Tesseract4.

Comment: @themm, i  am getting following error when installing the package:error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Answer (score 0):

You may try below. It works for `Tesseract 4.0.0a` with `Python 3.6`.

```
ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang="eng",\
      boxes=False, config="--psm 3 --oem 2")
```

`--psm 3` is the default Page Segmentation Mode.

Hope this help.